# Python urllib2/requests with NTLMv2 proxy authentication

Tags: python, proxy

I need to get Python to authenticate with a NTLMv2 HTTP proxy before I can make HTTP requests.

As Python doesn't natively support this, and I can't use any non-standard packages, what is the best intermediate proxy software I can install on Windows to handle NTLMv2 authentication with the NTLMv2 proxy server?

Ideally I don't want to authenticate every HTTP request I make with Python.

I just want to set the Python proxy to use the local proxy installed on Windows, and the Windows local proxy software handles authentication.

Thanks.

Comment: using squid cache proxy